# Epoch time around 5 mins per epoch?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, epoch

I made a post before containing my source code, after training a custom CNN model, I run 30 epochs, however, they take around 5 mins each to complete.

Does anyone know how to improve the time it takes per epoch because it took me almost 3 hours to complete the first time running?

Thank you!

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, AveragePooling2D, Input, BatchNormalization, MaxPooling2D, Activation, Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from keras.models import Model
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler
from keras.preprocessing import image
import scipy
import os
from random import randint
import gc
data = pd.read_csv('/com.docker.devenvironments.code/fer2013/icml_face_data.csv')
pixel_data = data[' pixels']
label_data = data['emotion']
len(label_data)
def preprocess_pixels(pixel_data):
  images = []
  for i in range(len(pixel_data)):
    img = np.fromstring(pixel_data[i], dtype='int', sep=' ')
    img = img.reshape(48,48,1)
    images.append(img)

  X = np.array(images)
  return X


oversampler = RandomOverSampler(sampling_strategy='auto')

X_over, Y_over = oversampler.fit_resample(pixel_data.values.reshape(-1,1), label_data)
X_over_series = pd.Series(X_over.flatten())
X_over_series
X = preprocess_pixels(X_over_series)
Y = Y_over
Y = Y_over.values.reshape(Y.shape[0],1)
Y.shape
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.1, random_state = 45)
print(X_train.shape, Y_train.shape)
plt.imshow(X[10000,:,:,0])
def emotion_recognition(input_shape):

  X_input = Input(input_shape)

  X = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid')(X_input)
  X = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X)
  X = Activation('relu')(X)


  X = Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding = 'same')(X)
  X = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X)
  X = Activation('relu')(X)

  X = MaxPooling2D((2,2))(X)

  X = Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding = 'valid')(X)
  X = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X)
  X = Activation('relu')(X)

  X = Conv2D(128, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding = 'same')(X)
  X = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X)
  X = Activation('relu')(X)


  X = MaxPooling2D((2,2))(X)

  X = Conv2D(128, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding = 'valid')(X)
  X = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(X)
  X = Activation('relu')(X)

 

  X = MaxPooling2D((2,2))(X)
  X = Flatten()(X)
  X = Dense(200, activation='relu')(X)
  X = Dropout(0.6)(X)
  X = Dense(7, activation = 'softmax')(X)
  model = Model(inputs=X_input, outputs=X)
  

  return model
model = emotion_recognition((48,48,1))
adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
y_train = to_categorical(Y_train, num_classes=7)
y_test = to_categorical(Y_test, num_classes=7)

preds = model.predict(X_train)
def get_class(preds):
  pred_class = np.zeros((preds.shape[0],1))

  for i in range(len(preds)):
   pred_class[i] = np.argmax(preds[i])

  return pred_class

pred_class_train = get_class(preds)
label_dict = {0 : 'Angry', 1 : 'Disgust', 2 : 'Fear', 3 : 'Happiness', 4 : 'Sad', 5 : 'Surprise', 6 : 'Neutral'}

checkpoint_path = "/com.docker.devenvironments.code/Checkpoints/cp.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path, save_weights_only=True, verbose=1)

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 30, validation_data=(X_test,y_test), callbacks=[cp_callback])
img_path = '/com.docker.devenvironments.code/fer2013/testimgs/surprise/PublicTest_97995446.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, grayscale=True, target_size=(48,48,1))

x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

prediction = np.argmax(model.predict(x))
print('The predicted emotion is : ' + label_dict[prediction])
my_image = image.load_img(img_path)
plt.imshow(my_image)
```

The following is the epoch progress output when running:

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 48, 48, 1)]       0         
                                                                 
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 46, 46, 32)        320       
                                                                 
 batch_normalization (BatchN  (None, 46, 46, 32)       128       
 ormalization)                                                   
                                                                 
 activation (Activation)     (None, 46, 46, 32)        0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 46, 46, 64)        18496     
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_1 (Batc  (None, 46, 46, 64)       256       
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 activation_1 (Activation)   (None, 46, 46, 64)        0         
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D  (None, 23, 23, 64)       0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 conv2d_2 (Conv2D)           (None, 21, 21, 64)        36928     
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_2 (Batc  (None, 21, 21, 64)       256       
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 activation_2 (Activation)   (None, 21, 21, 64)        0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_3 (Conv2D)           (None, 21, 21, 128)       73856     
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_3 (Batc  (None, 21, 21, 128)      512       
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 activation_3 (Activation)   (None, 21, 21, 128)       0         
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling  (None, 10, 10, 128)      0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_4 (Conv2D)           (None, 8, 8, 128)         147584    
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_4 (Batc  (None, 8, 8, 128)        512       
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 activation_4 (Activation)   (None, 8, 8, 128)         0         
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling  (None, 4, 4, 128)        0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 2048)              0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 200)               409800    
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 200)               0         
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 7)                 1407      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 690,055
Trainable params: 689,223
Non-trainable params: 832
_________________________________________________________________

Epoch 1/30
2022-04-14 18:16:48.070967: W tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:82] Allocation of 1043804160 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
1770/1770 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.7024 - accuracy: 0.3334
Epoch 1: saving model to /com.docker.devenvironments.code/Checkpoints/cp.ckpt
1770/1770 [==============================] - 289s 163ms/step - loss: 1.7024 - accuracy: 0.3334 - val_loss: 1.3777 - val_accuracy: 0.4834
Epoch 2/30
 315/1770 [====>.........................] - ETA: 3:52 - loss: 1.4277 - accuracy: 0.4498
```

Comment: It is based on your hardware.. are you training on GPU or CPU?

Comment: Its using my CPU i believe, when opening task manager almost 100% cpu is used

Comment: Yeah then that's probably the main reason it is taking this long. Faster model training typically requires a GPU since GPU's can perform multiple, simultaneous computations. If you don't have one, I would recommend using Kaggle or Google Colab's cloud GPU's for free.

Comment: Have you got any idea how id incorporate that into my code? im a complete newbie to all of this haha

Comment: If you are using tensorflow, you can check out this page: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu which gives documentation regarding the usage of a gpu for training.